# android and SQL Server

Tags: java, android

i am developing an application that reads and writes data remotely on an SQL Server, the application is ment to run on an android devices.
i know that i have to make a java server that uses socket connetion to the android app, i did that and the server connect normally using MS JDBC driver and excutes sql queries and send the result as a "single String" to the client and the client subString that massive junk of data
the problem is, whenever the clients connect to the server and try to fetch data it hangs during the receive process!!
is there is something wrong with my approach "data size might be huge sometimes, over 30000 rows"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be sure that you are making an asynchronous call to your server. That will keep it from hanging. Also, you might be better off writing a web service that is essentially an abstraction of your data so that it can be hosted on an app server. This will scale much better.